# (Python) How to loop a certain area of code with a 'n' variable number of times

Tags: python

```
def player_choice():

    while True:

        roundsplayed = int(input("Choose how many rounds you want to play from 1 to 5! "))

        if roundsplayed < 1 or roundsplayed > 5:
            print ("Please enter a valid number from 1 to 5! ")
            continue
        return player_choice
    else:
        print ("Lets play " + roundsplayed + "rounds! ")

roundsplayed = player_choice()

print ("Let's go go go!")




options = ("r", "p", "s", "l", "sp")
from random import randint
computer = options[randint(0,4)]

for i in range(roundsplayed):

    wins = 0
    loses = 0
    draws = 0

    player = input("""Choose your hand!
    Rock (r)
    Paper (p)
    Scissor (s)
    Lizard (l)
    Spock (s)
    Your Choice: """)



    # if player chooses rock
    if player == "r" and computer == "r":
        print ("You tied!")

    elif player == "r" and computer == "s":
        print ("You crushed them! You Win!")
        wins += 1
        print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))

    elif player == "r" and computer == "p":
        print ("You got covered! You lose!")
        loses += 1
        print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))

    elif player == "r" and computer == "l":
        print ("You crushed them! You Win!")
        wins += 1
        print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))

    elif player == "r" and computer == "sp":
        print ("You got vaporized! You lose!")
        loses += 1
        print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))
```

So I have this line of code

```
for i in range(roundsplayed):

wins = 0
loses = 0
draws = 0

player = input("""Choose your hand!
Rock (r)
Paper (p)
Scissor (s)
Lizard (l)
Spock (s)
Your Choice: """)



# if player chooses rock
if player == "r" and computer == "r":
    print ("You tied!")

elif player == "r" and computer == "s":
    print ("You crushed them! You Win!")
    wins += 1
    print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))

elif player == "r" and computer == "p":
    print ("You got covered! You lose!")
    loses += 1
    print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))

elif player == "r" and computer == "l":
    print ("You crushed them! You Win!")
    wins += 1
    print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))

elif player == "r" and computer == "sp":
    print ("You got vaporized! You lose!")
    loses += 1
    print ("Wins: {} Draws: {} Loses: {}".format(wins, draws, loses))
```

And want to make it repeat the number of times I want it to loop by entering a certain variable or input. I put the 'roundsplayed' variable there in the idea that the code would accept a variable entered by the user.

Obviously this doesn't work because the code doesn't define it as an interger.

Also for:

```
 wins = 0
loses = 0
draws = 0
```

I want it to tally up when the rounds restart to the start of the loop, but obviously have a problem with that as whenever it chooses to restart the loop, the tally is reset to 0, most likely from by obvious mistake.

I hope somebody can help me out, this is all that needs to be fixed for my coding as a python learner, so that I can move on to my next project.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to an integer,

```
int("stringhere")
```

If you don't want variables reset every time you loop, take them out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the variables in the loop without reset it them, declare them above of the loop (outside the loop).

```
 wins = 0
    loses = 0
    draws = 0
for i in range(roundsplayed):


    player = input("""Choose your hand!
    Rock (r)
    Paper (p)
    Scissor (s)
    Lizard (l)
    Spock (s)
    Your Choice: """)
```

If you wanna cast a string you got from the console to an int, you can use the Int() function.

```
var number = int("1")
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: Hmm...I don't exactly get where to put the [var number = int("1")

Comment: I think you don't need it. You already cast your variable to int here
 roundsplayed = int(input("Choose how many rounds you want to play from 1 to 5! "))